# PyOpenGL - import error: No module named GL

Tags: python, pyopengl

I recently installed pythonxy and tried to run code which start with (in Eclipse):

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
```

and got

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
ImportError: No module named GL
```

I uninstalled pythonxy, install full version of EPD and the same error...

sys.path gave me:

```
['D:\\eclipse-java-indigo-SR2-   win32\\eclipse\\plugins\\org.python.pydev_2.7.1.2012100913\\pysrc',
'C:\\Users\\Kuba\\workspace\\python\\ThinkPython\\src',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pyopengl-3.0.2-py2.7-win32.egg',
'C:\\Python27\\python27.zip',
'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python27\\lib',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
'C:\\Python27',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions']
```

As you can see - I'm working on Windows machine.

I saw similar questions here, but nothing helped...

I'm new to python - maybe solution is simple...

Any suggestions ?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You have an installation issue with your `PyOpenGL` module. Older versions of EPD (pre 6.2-1) had an issue with the 64bit `PyOpenGL` package - you may need to update EPD.

Alternatively, you could try to install through `easy_install`

```
C:\Python27\scripts\easy_install pyopengl
```

or `pip`

```
C:\Python27\scripts\pip pyopengl
```

or using the binaries on Christoph Gohlke's [site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl).

Personally I'd recommend installing Chris' binaries - they've always worked well for me.

Comment: In the meantime I returned to pythonxy and realized that in SCITE my code works! But in eclipse still not... I also installed Chris' binaries and still same error in eclipse (but in SCITE all ok)...

Comment: Does eclipse include it's own python binary? This might explain that oddness.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error for filename is OpenGL.py.
If your file's name is the same, try renaming it.